# Getting all network info

Tags: networking, 20.04, bash

I’ve been wondering if I’m Ubuntu, or Linux in general, there is any single utility that can get all the common networking settings. I guess on windows it would have been ipconfig. I’m using Ubuntu Server 20.04. I’m looking for

- ip
- subnet
- gateway
- dns
- dhcp

Right now I’m doing all of this by parsing various outputs from

- ip a
- ip r
- resolvectl

Or in python I was using

- netifaces
- shell script to capture dns and dhcp

I was curious if there was an easier way? Even if it includes loading a package.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

create shell script file (network.sh)
paste this code

```
#!/bin/bash

IP4FW=/sbin/iptables
IP6FW=/sbin/ip6tables
LSPCI=/usr/bin/lspci
ROUTE=/sbin/route
NETSTAT=/bin/netstat
LSB=/usr/bin/lsb_release

## files ##
DNSCLIENT="/etc/resolv.conf"
DRVCONF="/etc/modprobe.conf"
NETALIASCFC="/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth?-range?"
NETCFC="/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth?"
NETSTATICROUTECFC="/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth?"
SYSCTL="/etc/sysctl.conf"

## Output file ##
OUTPUT="network.$(date +'%d-%m-%y').info.txt"


chk_root() {
    local meid=$(id -u)
    if [ $meid -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "You must be root user to run this tool"
        exit 999
    fi
}

write_header() {
    echo "---------------------------------------------------" >>$OUTPUT
    echo "$@" >>$OUTPUT
    echo "---------------------------------------------------" >>$OUTPUT
}

dump_info() {
    echo "* Hostname: $(hostname)" >$OUTPUT
    echo "* Run date and time: $(date)" >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "Linux Distro"
    echo "Linux kernel: $(uname -mrs)" >>$OUTPUT
    $LSB -a >>$OUTPUT

    [ -x ${HWINF} ] && write_header "${HWINF}"
    [ -x ${HWINF} ] && ${HWINF} >>$OUTPUT

    [ -x ${HWINF} ] && write_header "${HWINF}"
    [ -x ${HWINF} ] && ${HWINF} >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "PCI Devices"
    ${LSPCI} -v >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "$IFCFG Output"
    $IFCFG >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "Kernel Routing Table"
    $ROUTE -n >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "Network Card Drivers Configuration $DRVCONF"
    [ -f $DRVCONF ] && grep eth $DRVCONF >>$OUTPUT || echo "Error $DRVCONF file not found." >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "DNS Client $DNSCLIENT Configuration"
    [ -f $DNSCLIENT ] && cat $DNSCLIENT >>$OUTPUT || echo "Error $DNSCLIENT file not found." >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "Network Configuration File"
    for f in $NETCFC; do
        if [ -f $f ]; then
            echo "** $f **" >>$OUTPUT
            cat $f >>$OUTPUT
        else
            echo "Error $f not found." >>$OUTPUT
        fi
    done

    write_header "Network Aliase File"
    for f in $NETALIASCFC; do
        if [ -f $f ]; then
            echo "** $f **" >>$OUTPUT
            cat $f >>$OUTPUT
        else
            echo "Error $f not found." >>$OUTPUT
        fi
    done

    write_header "Network Static Routing Configuration"
    for f in $NETSTATICROUTECFC; do
        if [ -f $f ]; then
            echo "** $f **" >>$OUTPUT
            cat $f >>$OUTPUT
        else
            echo "Error $f not found." >>$OUTPUT
        fi
    done

    write_header "IP4 Firewall Configuration"
    $IP4FW -L -n >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "IP6 Firewall Configuration"
    $IP6FW -L -n >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "Network Stats"
    $NETSTAT -s >>$OUTPUT

    write_header "Network Tweaks via $SYSCTL"
    [ -f $SYSCTL ] && cat $SYSCTL >>$OUTPUT || echo "Error $SYSCTL not found." >>$OUTPUT

    echo "The Network Configuration Info Written To $OUTPUT."
}

chk_root
dump_info
```

Make file executable:

```
chmod +x network.sh
```